# Autofill advanced custom field with user data

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, users, advanced-custom-fields, user-meta

I'm developing a new site where you can log in as a user and post messages yourself (custom post type).

They can fill in or select the largest part of the data themselves, but a few fields have to be filled automatically and are not visible when placing the message.

As an example, I have an advanced custom field called "name_provider" with this ID "field_5b0bc22b22606" and I want this field to be filled automatically with the username of the user who is currently logged in.

When someone places a message, his username is automatically placed in that field. However, that field may not be visible or editable.

Is such a thing possible or is this something that can not be realized?

I have researched the internet quite a bit but have not come across anything.

Someone here an idea how I can realize the above?

**EDIT**

Ok, I managed to get this far:

```
function set_acf_field_default_value( $field ) {
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    switch ( $field['name'] ) {
        case 'name_provivder':
            $field['value'] = '' . $current_user->user_login .'';
            break;
    }

    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field', 'set_acf_field_default_value' );
```

This is working great! Now I only have one question.

When the logged in user creating a new post he is able to edit this field. How can I make those fields un-editable? Or can I hide those fields?

**EDIT 2**

Ok, I managed to get this working:

```
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=name_provivder', 'disable_acf_prepare_field');

function disable_acf_prepare_field( $field ) {

        // Does the user have an Office role?
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
               if ( in_array( 'brons', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
                  $usergroup = 'brons';
               }

    switch($field['_name']) {   
        // Which field are we looking for?  
        case 'name_provivder':
                 if ($usergroup == 'brons') {
                  // Set the CLASS of the field to use css to hide
                  $field['wrapper']['class'] = 'hide';
                   }
            break;
    }
return $field;
}

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    .hide {
      display:none;
    } 
  </style>';
}
```

This is hiding this specific field if a user is "brons", is it possible to hide a whole group? Cant fine anything in documentation. Anybody got an idea?

Comment: Can you try JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done (it's almost always true ;))... The question is how to do this? ;)

And here is the solution... You'll have to use `acf/load_field` filter:

```
function set_acf_field_default_value( $field ) {
    switch ( $field['name'] ) {
        case 'name_provider':
            $field['value'] = 'PUT YOUR VALUE HERE';
            break;
    }

    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field', 'set_acf_field_default_value' );
```

PS. Of course you can use `if` statement in there, but you rarely want to prefill only one field, so it's easier to do this with `switch`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and that worked. So now I only wil have to get the username of the user that is currently logged in and put it there. I will try to figure this out.:)

Comment: And what do you mean by "username"? Login? Displayname? First name + last name?

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer, almost there:) Maybo you know a way to hide those fields?

Comment: @user2812779 you can hide them using ACF options, I guess. Or just use JS script on the form and make them read-only if the user is logged in (based on body class)

Comment: I edited my anser, got it working on user level and it is hiding the field. Do you know how to do this for a whole group? Cant find in anywhere

Comment: If you want to hide all group, then you can use ACF settings and show the group only if current user satisfies your condition.